# Player Jiggles When Running Into Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I've been trying to fix this player collision script that I have but I can't figure out why. It's supposed to stop the player from running through walls, but when my player runs up against a wall, it jiggles around a ton like the script isn't running fast enough. (This code is from Sebastian Lagues coding tutorial series.)

The script:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
    {
    Rigidbody myRigidbody;
    public float speed = 5f;
    Vector3 velocity;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        Vector3 direction = input.normalized;
        velocity = direction * speed;
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        myRigidbody.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider triggerCollider) {
        print(triggerCollider.gameObject.name);

    }
}
```

When I enabled Interpolate on the player and used MovePosition, it jiggled even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the rigidbody's `collisionDetectionMode` to `Continous`

I would also remove your `velocity` variable and set `myRigidbody.velocity` in `FixedUpdate`, like so:

```
void Update() {
}
void FixedUpdate() {
    Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    Vector3 direction = input.normalized;
    myRigidbody.velocity = direction * speed;
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CollisionDetectionMode.html

Comment: Thank you so much! the only issue is that I have to freeze the rotation, but I don't need 
rotation anyway.